# Solve $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2+\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}+y=0$

Tags: calculus

Is it possible to solve an equation such as
$$
\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^2+\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}+y=0
$$
for $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$

Comment: That is quadratic in $\theta '$.

Comment: Replace the word 'derivative' with a variable and you recover a high school problem.

Comment: Is y a function of $t$ or $\theta$?

Comment: are you sure you really mean $$\left( \frac{d\theta}{dt} \right)^2 + \frac{d\theta}{dt} + y = 0$$ and not $$\frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2}+ \frac{d\theta}{dt} + y = 0?$$

Comment: Do you just want to find an expression for the derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is a simple second degree equation: Put $x=d \theta/ dt$ and solve:
$$
x^2+x+y=0
$$